# writing to a file , and save one

Tags: python

I would like why when I tried to save my tokens to my save always save the first one

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random
import string

count = 1
while count <= 5:
    t = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation
    key = str(''.join(random.sample(t,33)))
    with open('keys','w') as keys:
        keys.write(key)
    count += 1
```

Comment: everytime you open your ``keys`` file, you delete all content in your file. I do not know what you want to do so I can't help you more.

Comment: I want to save my 5 rounds from my while to my file , but only save the first one

Comment: no, it's only save the last. if you want to do this, you can initialise a list, append it every loop and save in your ``keys`` file outside the loop

Comment: Do you really want all the output to be on a single line like that? Or do you want each `key` string to be written to a separate line?

Comment: I fix it , but for example if I have the first 5 added how can I check which ones are the new keys in the same file?

Comment: The chance of creating a duplicate key is **very** small, even if you run the program for billions of years. But if you want to check you need to read the old lines from the file into a set (or a list), and then before you write each new key you need to see if it's in the set of existing keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random
import string

count = 1
with open('keys','w') as keys:
    while count <= 5:
       t = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation
       key = str(''.join(random.sample(t,33)))
       keys.write(key)
       count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the the file than to write it every time i.e. use 'a' instead of 'w' in `open` as -

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random
import string

count = 1
while count <= 5:
    t = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation
    key = str(''.join(random.sample(t,33)))
    with open('keys','a') as keys:
        keys.write(key)
    count += 1
```

You may also need to add newline after the each key.

> always save the first one

No, your code doesn't saves the first key, but instead the last key generated.